# pdfkit does not load css and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, css, flask, pdfkit

I'm currently building a web application using `Flask`. My supervisor requested that one feature should be to save the current page as a PDF (for printing). To this end I'm using `pdfkit`. Before anyone proposes to use `weasyprint` instead: I tried installing it for 2 hours to no avail, so I've abandoned that. I'm using the `Bootstrap` css and its JavaScript to make the application a bit more pleasant to look upon.

I'm using the below file structure (as proposed by a tutorial to `Flask`)

```
+-- name_of_app
|   +-- static
|       +-- css
|           +-- css files
|       +-- js
|           +-- javascript files
|   +-- templates
|       +-- .html templates
|   +-- __init__.py
|   +-- config.py
|   +-- forms.py
|   +-- views.py
+-- run.py
```

To just try `pdfkit` out, I generate PDFs every time I generate a page, i.e. in all of the functions which are routed in `views.py`. All the pages are based on the following template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="static\css\bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="static\css\bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="static\js\bootstrap.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        {% if title %}
        <title>{{ title }} - Timeseries Project</title>
        {% else %}
        <title>Welcome to the Timeseries Project</title>
        {% endif %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <a class="navbar-brand active" href="/">Home</a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Save as PDF</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

The web pages load beautifully using the provided css and JS files. However, `pdfkit` outputs the following warnings

```
Warning: Failed to load file:///C:/Users/my_user/AppData/Local/Temp/static/css/bootstrap.css (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///C:/Users/my_user/AppData/Local/Temp/static/css/bootstrap-theme.css (ignore)
Warning: Failed to load file:///C:/Users/my_user/AppData/Local/Temp/static/js/bootstrap.js (ignore)
```

The issue I'm trying to resolve is therefore: How do I get `pdfkit` to look for `static` in the folder where one of its methods was executed (i.e. `views.py`), and not in `AppData`?

Comment: Is a print-only stylesheet not an option due to the nature of the app?

Comment: Hmm, not really sure what "print-only stylesheet" means I'm afraid, could you elaborate? (I have no experience from web development)

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: Thanks! I'll read it tomorrow after I've tried rmn's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To generate URLs for static files, use the special `'static'` endpoint name: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#static-files

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap-theme.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Update:**
Using `_external=True` may also fix the issue by providing an absolute url. eg:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css', _external=True) }}" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Comment: Wow, if it's this simple I'm going to lay down and cry. Thank you so much for the answer, will try it out when I'm at the office tomorrow and get back to you

Comment: Hmm, I tried implementing this, however I now get the same warnings but for path `Failed to load file:///static/css/bootstrap-theme.css`

Comment: try with absolute URL: `url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css',  _external=True)`

Comment: Now it finds it correctly, thanks! However, the issue is now that `pdfkit` won't save the file... Probably has something to with it being locally hosted...

Comment: This was the solution, thank you. And also to ditch `pdfkit` and use `wkhtmltopdf-wrapper` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work using `pdfkit` by including the full path in my `jinja2` template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///Users/paul/code/pdfmaker/templates/css/styles.css">
```